# IF "Green" is picked from down down list clear other cell

Tags: excel, list, if-statement

Excel:

In D23 I have a drop down list with the options of Red, Amber, Green, Complete, Cancelled, On Hold. In E23 I enter a date of when the project will go Green if it is in any of the other states.

I would like E23 to be empty if D23 is Green. Otherwise E23 should be able to have a date typed in i.e 10/02/2016... any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel conditional formatting you can get this job done..

for more about conditional formatting refer this page related to what your looking for : http://www.excel-formulas.in/2015/08/excel-conditional-formatting-excel.html